# How to split data text file with equal elements in the row into several files in MATLAB or Fortran?

Tags: matlab, fortran

I am not an expert in matlab and use it for simple calculations in physics. I have never tried data mining with it. However, at the moment, I want to split data text file with equal elements in the row into several files. The blocks of the text file that needs to be separated into several files are separated by a blank line. I want to store the information in arrays. The test data set can be found here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lRuQIx0QzVhMFtROQOJC3uJcg_Fbvfoq/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to create a small script that writes all blocks in the original file into separate output files that contain only one block. Ideally these files would be named as the name as data1.txt data2.txt and so on where 1 and 2 are the number of blocks. Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any change you could post a sample text file to work with? Depending on how your data is formatted the way to retrieve the data may vary. It'll be easier than working from the image posted.

Comment: I just  added a link to a portion of the data. Hope this works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to change the access. Easiest would be to copy and paste it as a code block in the question.

Comment: Just changed the access. Might be easier incase you need to download. it's just 10-12 lines though. Don't have much experience with data mining. Thanks

Comment: I still dont exactly know what output format you actually want. Could you include the expected output in the question? e.g. should we strip the "X,Y,Z" and "1 S", etc. from the blocks?

Comment: I agree with @jack. Since you want the data in arrays did you want to also strip the of `X, Y, Z` and `1 S, 2 S, 3 S`? Also, the format of the arrays you'd like would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. I wanted to paste the entire blocks separated with a blank lines in multiple file. Now, I will just read an additional loop over the files and will store the numeric values in arrays in each file and the perform statistical operations based on the arrays. My main difficulty was getting it in a suitable format. Now the operations shall be straight forward for me. Incase I have doubts I will post a question in this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I've created that can be called by:

[Here's the function uploaded to GitHub](https://github.com/MichaelTr7/StackOverflow/tree/master/Tutorial%2058:%20Dividing%20Text%20File%20Into%20Subsections)

### Function Call:

```
File_Name = "Tryout.txt";
Subsection_Text(File_Name);
```

The code below isn't the most concise but it should do the trick. It parses the text file line by line using the function `fgetl()`. The blank lines are used as delimiters for starting a new file. The tricky part involved the way MATLAB can evaluate spaces as a character. Using the fact that every line in this data set either has an `X, Y or Z` character sets the definition for what constitutes as a line.

### Full Script:

```
clear;
clc;

Mode = 'rt'; 
File_ID = fopen("Tryout.txt",Mode);
Break_Condition = 0;

Line_Index = 1;

while(Break_Condition < 3)

Text = string(fgetl(File_ID));
 
Empty = ~contains(Text,["X" "Y" "Z"]);

if(~Empty)
Break_Condition = 0;
Lines(Line_Index,1) = Text;
end    

if(Empty)
Break_Condition = Break_Condition + 1;   
Lines(Line_Index,1) = "";
end
   
Line_Index = Line_Index + 1;
end

Lines = Lines(1:length(Lines)-3);
fclose(File_ID);

Break_Condition = 0;
Block_Index = 1; 

Save_File_ID = fopen("data" + num2str(Block_Index) +".txt",'w');

for Line_Index = 1: length(Lines)
Print_Text = Lines(Line_Index,1);



if(Print_Text ~= "")
Break_Condition = 0;
fprintf(Save_File_ID,"%s",Lines(Line_Index,1));
fprintf(Save_File_ID,"\n");
end


if(Print_Text == "")
Break_Condition = Break_Condition + 1;
if(Break_Condition == 2)
fprintf("Start new file\n");
Block_Index = Block_Index + 1;
Save_File_ID = fopen("data" + num2str(Block_Index) +".txt",'w');
end
    
end
```

### Results:

### Tryout.txt

```
  1   S            X  0.00026468  0.05840333 -0.00000503  0.00000220 -0.00006671
                   Y  0.01038702 -0.00000313  0.00000194  0.00000252  0.05330246
                   Z -0.00000018  0.00000340  0.04070305  0.00007263 -0.00000140
  2   S            X  0.00014171  0.03011383  0.00010166 -0.05798360 -0.00000669
                   Y  0.04058891 -0.00017498  0.00020915 -0.00000008  0.01402693
                   Z -0.03503189  0.00020203  0.04033549  0.00007595  0.04355313
  3   S            X  0.00014261  0.03010885 -0.00010647  0.05798668 -0.00001234
                   Y  0.04058889 -0.00017504 -0.00020776  0.00000080  0.01402683
                   Z  0.03503150 -0.00019534  0.04033281  0.00007114 -0.04355608

                   
  1   S            X  0.04356337 -0.00000001  0.02077084  0.00000015  0.00000034
                   Y  0.00002152 -0.00000006  0.00000140  0.00000007  0.00877642
                   Z  0.00000016  0.00000034  0.00000006 -0.01895397 -0.00000002
  2   S            X -0.03932055  0.00258729 -0.03252282  0.00000100  0.00000117
                   Y  0.00000868 -0.00000106  0.00000134 -0.03714789  0.00961379
                   Z  0.00001393  0.00000251 -0.00000096  0.05653194 -0.05987231
  3   S            X -0.03931981 -0.00258731 -0.03252280 -0.00000137  0.00000116
                   Y  0.00000868  0.00000102  0.00000088  0.03714794  0.00961382
                   Z -0.00001360  0.00000259  0.00000015  0.05653178  0.05987235


  1   S            X  0.00000001 -0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000003  0.00000000
                   Y -0.00000002  0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.00993526  0.00000000
                   Z -0.03154647  0.00000025  0.02119553  0.00000000  0.00793086
  2   S            X  0.00000002  0.01626500 -0.00000011  0.00000003 -0.00000006
                   Y  0.04786716 -0.00000021 -0.02203705  0.01792716  0.02061079
                   Z  0.00338406  0.00000018  0.03888413 -0.02145517  0.01502515
  3   S            X -0.00000002 -0.01626500  0.00000011  0.00000003  0.00000006
                   Y -0.04786706  0.00000021  0.02203705  0.01792717 -0.02061079
                   Z  0.00338411  0.00000018  0.03888412  0.02145518  0.01502514
```

### data1.txt

```
  1   S            X  0.00026468  0.05840333 -0.00000503  0.00000220 -0.00006671
                   Y  0.01038702 -0.00000313  0.00000194  0.00000252  0.05330246
                   Z -0.00000018  0.00000340  0.04070305  0.00007263 -0.00000140
  2   S            X  0.00014171  0.03011383  0.00010166 -0.05798360 -0.00000669
                   Y  0.04058891 -0.00017498  0.00020915 -0.00000008  0.01402693
                   Z -0.03503189  0.00020203  0.04033549  0.00007595  0.04355313
  3   S            X  0.00014261  0.03010885 -0.00010647  0.05798668 -0.00001234
                   Y  0.04058889 -0.00017504 -0.00020776  0.00000080  0.01402683
                   Z  0.03503150 -0.00019534  0.04033281  0.00007114 -0.04355608
```

### data2.txt

```
  1   S            X  0.04356337 -0.00000001  0.02077084  0.00000015  0.00000034
                   Y  0.00002152 -0.00000006  0.00000140  0.00000007  0.00877642
                   Z  0.00000016  0.00000034  0.00000006 -0.01895397 -0.00000002
  2   S            X -0.03932055  0.00258729 -0.03252282  0.00000100  0.00000117
                   Y  0.00000868 -0.00000106  0.00000134 -0.03714789  0.00961379
                   Z  0.00001393  0.00000251 -0.00000096  0.05653194 -0.05987231
  3   S            X -0.03931981 -0.00258731 -0.03252280 -0.00000137  0.00000116
                   Y  0.00000868  0.00000102  0.00000088  0.03714794  0.00961382
                   Z -0.00001360  0.00000259  0.00000015  0.05653178  0.05987235
```

### data3.txt

```
  1   S            X  0.00000001 -0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000003  0.00000000
                   Y -0.00000002  0.00000000 -0.00000000 -0.00993526  0.00000000
                   Z -0.03154647  0.00000025  0.02119553  0.00000000  0.00793086
  2   S            X  0.00000002  0.01626500 -0.00000011  0.00000003 -0.00000006
                   Y  0.04786716 -0.00000021 -0.02203705  0.01792716  0.02061079
                   Z  0.00338406  0.00000018  0.03888413 -0.02145517  0.01502515
  3   S            X -0.00000002 -0.01626500  0.00000011  0.00000003  0.00000006
                   Y -0.04786706  0.00000021  0.02203705  0.01792717 -0.02061079
                   Z  0.00338411  0.00000018  0.03888412  0.02145518  0.01502514
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was of immense help. Kind regards :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :)